# Scale down all page content with Polymer

Tags: css, polymer

Polymer makes by default nice but airy layouts (due to paddings, margins, font sizes...).

What is the official (or clean) way to scale down all the user interface so that we can have more content on fewer surface?

I could find a quick hack with:

```
html {
    transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

but this shifts all the content, leaving an empty space on each 4 borders.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D Here are (I hope) all the necessary details to understand.

Comment: Nope...not even close really.

Comment: Polymer itself doesn't dictate page design or layout, it's just a library for creating custom elements. I'm guessing you're actually using the Polymer Starter Kit, which includes some default page layouts and styles. Please update your question to include that information, and be specific about what you're trying to change (font size, padding between certain elements, etc)

Comment: Up to now (it's my 1st steps with Polymer), I'm using paper-button, paper-card, iron-icon(s). For instance, on the Desktop, paper-button have by default a padding ~10px and margin ~5px, a font-height of 16px. And paper-card and the others that I can see in the doc https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=paper-elements seems to be built on the same graphic identity.
@Zikes I installed Polymer with bower. Didn't know about the starter kit before.

Comment: The question is about making everything looking more compact. Less space in and between each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it with the CSS mixins. For instance to override every paper-button layout, I added the following css to the main html file :

```
:host {
    --paper-button: {
        padding: 3px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

According to https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-button , this is injected to the end of each paper-button css.